# Get updated URL to facebook user's profile pic

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api, fetch

I am using facebook's graph api to get basic info about a user.
While sending a request to `/me?fields=id,name,picture`, I get the following response

```json
{
  "id": "645636655991071",
  "name": "Rahul Dahal",
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "height": 50,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=645636655991071&height=50&width=50&ext=1619960875&hash=AeSav5aZhqO_ExOLOPc",
      "width": 50
    }
  }
}
```

The `url` property of the `picture` object has the URL to the picture, but it expires after certain period of time.

This means I cannot store that URL in the database.

How can I get the updated URL to the picture ?

Comment: _“How can I get the updated URL to the picture ?”_ - by making the same request again …?

Comment: If you use the `/{user-id}/picture` endpoint directly, then you don’t need to store the actual image URLs; but you might have to append an access token to the request under certain conditions, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/#requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```css
.fit-picture {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img class="fit-picture"
     src="https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=645636655991071&height=50&width=50&ext=1619960875&hash=AeSav5aZhqO_ExOLOPc"
     alt="Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices">
```

Comment: it does work. But, I came to understand that the url will expire after certain time.
Do you know by any chance how to get the updated url ?